# For loop is not displaying all the classes from website

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to do something to sum all of my minutes spent in League of Legends.
I want to get all classes which store minutes on official LoL match history. 
Now I am doing something like that:

```
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.date-duration-duration');
var timeArr = Array.from(time);
for(var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++){
    timeArr[i].innerText;
}
```

and it gives me only innerText from the first element from Array. But when my for loop got just timeArr instead of timeArr[i].innerText it is showing all the selected elements but without innerText. What should I do to list every innerText from this array because next step that i want to do is to parseFloat all of those elements and sum them.

Can someone direct me?:)

I want to add that I am very beginner right now and I am just starting with JavaScript.

---

#### Screenshots

[image: HTML]

[image: WEB]

[image: JS NUMBER 1]

[image: JS NUMBER 2]

Comment: Have you tried `innerHTML` ?

Comment: Not the best idea to have `div` inside `span`

Comment: Yes but still it is showing only first element from array but instead of innerText ("20:47") it displays full div ("<div id="binding-61" class="binding" style="">20:47</div>

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Thanks for advice but it is official League of Legends website.

Comment: Anyway that's not the best structure.

Comment: Your code included in your post is much more helpful if you include all relevant HTML, CSS, Javascript, and not images of it.

Comment: @daniyal lukmanov ok I am not arguing just saying thanks:)

Comment: @jhecht ok I'll remember thanks:)

Comment: To help you out a little: for loops don't have a return value, i.e. you can't set a for loop equal to a variable. You're seeing some console wizardry by doing that directly into the console.

Comment: @Jhecht Thanks for that useful information. I did not even know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your results somewhere. In your example you just call property innerText on elements, without any asignment. For example you can do it this way:

```
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.date-duration-duration');
var timeArr = Array.from(time);
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++){
  result.push(timeArr[i].innerText);
}
```

Variable `result` will contain your values as strings. Then you can sum it

```
result.reduce((sum, value) => sum + parseInt(value), 0);
```

Comment: Every guy that helped me I appreciate it a lot but this one is the clearest for me personally, thank you guys btw.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.from` should work. Make sure you are actually grabbing the element containing the text.

You can query on either `.date-duration-duration > div` or simply `.date-duration-duration`.

```js
// You can use either Array.from or [].slice.call
var times = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.date-duration-duration > div'))
  .map(duration => duration.textContent); // innerHTML will return markup
  
console.log(times.join(', '));
```

```html
<span class="date-duration-duration"><div>00:00</div></span>
<span class="date-duration-duration"><div>06:00</div></span>
<span class="date-duration-duration"><div>12:00</div></span>
<span class="date-duration-duration"><div>18:00</div></span>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but could you explain me this code line by line because it seems a little bit complicated to me. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: It's basically your code, but utilizing the `Array.prototype.map` function to map every element from the array to its textContent value. It then logs the array, joined by the string `', '` to the console.

Comment: Wrap the selected elements in an array so that you can call map on it. The mapped values are the text of each element.

Answer (score 0):

use console.log

```
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.date-duration-duration');
var timeArr = Array.from(time);
for(var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++){
    console.log(timeArr[i].innerText);
}
```

By default, it logs only last data, incase of timeArr it one data with 15 elements.

Comment: _"By default, it logs only last data"_ - Who is _"it"_, and why do you think _"it"_ only logs the _last one_?

Comment: Thanks it worked too. But how do I sum all the elements displayed in the console right now? thank you a lot.

Comment: you want to some times ?

Comment: @Andreas 'it' means his chrome console here. when he doesnt specofies to log then it returns the last data .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine so far. If you `console.log` the expression in your for loop, the code is returning the time for each row:

```js
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.date-duration-duration');
var timeArr = Array.from(time);
for(var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++){
    console.log(timeArr[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="date-duration-duration">20:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">10:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">15:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">25:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">30:00</div>
```

The next step is to do something with that code. One way to do it is to add the values to an array:

```js
var time = document.querySelectorAll('.date-duration-duration');
var timeArr = Array.from(time);
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++){
    arr.push(timeArr[i].innerText);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="date-duration-duration">20:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">10:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">15:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">25:00</div>
<div class="date-duration-duration">30:00</div>
```

Now you have an array outside of the for loop that you can loop through, add the times together, etc.